# Get indexPath.row from tableView into cell

Tags: ios, xcode

EDIT: Question in short: How do I access the index of the cell from the UICell class? Because atm I get it only from the method in the UITableView class which is posted beneath.
*end of edit*

I have an iOS app and added a UITableView. I'm filling it with custom UICells and in the UITableView I use this method to delete a row and remove the objects from the datasource

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I also added a modify-button in the UICell, so I also have to access the datasource, but I can't because it is is the UITableView class and I can't access it from the UICell class.

What is the best solution for this? Do I have to create a class for my datasource and both classes (UITableView and UICell) access it? If so, how do I do that? Sorry I am new to MVC, please help :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be filling your table from an array, if this is the case, you can remove the array element at index(selected index) and reload tableview.

Comment: Did you even read what I wrote?  Thats exactly what I'm doing already

Comment: okay.. if you get to know which button you selected from which cell in the table, in tableview class .. will it resolve the issue??

Comment: Yes! I only need to know in which cell the pressed button is, because I can't get to the indexpath.row which is an integer only given back from the method I posted above

Comment: okay, then give tag values to the buttons same as the cell index and on button selection get the value of button tag.. will it work?

Comment: I would have to set the tags in the UICell class and I can't access the index from there. I get the index only from the method I posted above

Comment: assign the tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath method in tableView class

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best way is to implement the Pattern [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Regards.

```
#import "MySingleton.h"

@implementation MySingleton
+(MySingleton *) sharedInstance{
   static  MySingleton *inst = nil;

    @synchronized(self){
        if (!inst) {
            inst = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
   return inst;
}

@end
```

Comment: I bet it is, I will take a look at this when I need it, but for now I'm good with the solution above

Answer (score 1):

When I've needed to do things like that, my approach has been to use a `NSNotification`.  The cell fires a custom notification and attaches `self` as the notification object.  The data source listens for the notification and either handles the action itself or responds by extracting the cell object and sending whatever it needs back to it.